# Free proxy server for windows home server?

Tags: proxy, windows-home-server

I want to set up a proxy server to run on my windows home server.  Obviously I want it to be secure and only usable by me.  And it needs to be reasonably easy to set up and configure.

Does something like that already exist?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[FreeProxy](http://www.handcraftedsoftware.org/).  Here is an article [on how to use it with WHS](http://computingondemand.com/?p=1045).

Answer (score 1):

I use [ziproxy](http://ziproxy.sourceforge.net/), i find it easier to configure than freeproxy, and since it can compress heavily images, it's faster on a slow vpn
Here is the [windows build](http://scattered.marklowne.com/post/127540255/ziproxy-2-7-0-precompiled-binary-for-windows)